# ImageButton is not visible when adding to a tablerow dynamically

Tags: android, textview, imagebutton, tablerow, android-tablelayout

I am creating a form where the user enters his/her address and when the user saves the form, the flow goes to another activity where the users' name is shown one below the other. I am using TableLayout and in each TableRow I have a TextView which shows the name and an ImageButton beside the textview which can be used to delete the entry. Now when I run the app I can only see the TextView in the layout, the ImageButton is not visible.Can someone please help me where I am going wrong?

Here is part of my code:

```
if (requestCode == REC_INFO && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        RecipientArray = (ArrayList<Person>) data
                .getSerializableExtra("RecArray");

        TableLayout tbl = new TableLayout(this);
        TextView[] tv = new TextView[RecipientArray.size()];
        ImageButton delete_btns[] = new ImageButton[RecipientArray.size()];
        TableRow tr[] = new TableRow[RecipientArray.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < RecipientArray.size(); i++) {

            tv[i] = new TextView(this);
            tv[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fill_rece);
            Person p = RecipientArray.get(i);
            tv[i].setText(p.getName());
            tv[i].setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            delete_btns[i] = new ImageButton(this);
            delete_btns[i]
                    .setImageResource(R.drawable.ipad_postcare_landscape_from);
            delete_btns[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tr[i] = new TableRow(this);
            tr[i].addView(tv[i]);
            tr[i].addView(delete_btns[i]);
            tbl.addView(tr[i]);

        }
        recs_layout.addView(tbl);//I add the TableLayout to a RelativeLayout

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
delete_btns[i] = new ImageButton(this);
delete_btns[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.ipad_postcare_landscape_from);
delete_btns[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
Drawable d = delete_btns[i].getDrawable();
d.setBounds(0, 0, delete_btns[i].getWidth(), delete_btns[i].getHeight());
```

Comment: Thanks, for the response, I had made the button visible by adding the line added delete_btns[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); I then saw your answer and the last 2 lines. They don't make any difference.

Comment: If you can have a look at this question and suggest an answer..it will be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20754944/designing-the-tablelayout-which-has-to-be-added-dynamically-within-a-relativelay

Answer (score 0):

I think your `textview` is taking all the space in the table row try setting layout params for that as well

For ex:

```
tv[i].setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 2f));
```

And similarly for image button

```
delete_btns[i].setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                    0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1f));
```

And to table row

```
tr[i].setWeightSum(3f)
```

Here the third argument of `float` type is weight of the view as it is set to `1f` for both your image view and textview both will occupy equal space you can change it and set it what you need.

While using weight set width to 0dp for both textview and imageview

Comment: Thanks for your response. when you use tv[i].setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f)); the textview is not visible, but the button is visible. I have made both appear by using TableRow.LayoutParams.

Comment: If you can have a look at this question and suggest an answer..it will be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20754944/designing-the-tablelayout-which-has-to-be-added-dynamically-within-a-relativelay

Comment: Nothing is visible now

Comment: try to set table row's params as well  tr[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));