# Designing the TableLayout which has to be added dynamically within a RelativeLayout

Tags: android, imagebutton, tablerow, android-tablelayout

I have to create an activity which has the layout as shown in the attached image[image: The image describes the layout which is required.]. I am having problems with making it look close to as shown in the image.
In the previous activity a user enters his.her address and saves it. When saved a new row which contains a TextView and a ImageButton has to be created. The TextView shows name of the person and the ImageButton can be used to delete that person. Every time a new person's address is entered and saved, a new row must be created and therefore the add button keeps moving down to create a row. I have added the screenshot of how the layout looks currently.[image: Current Layout's screenshot] I am a beginner in android app programming and need some assistance. Kindly, please help me.

Here is part of my code:

```
if (requestCode == REC_INFO && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        RecipientArray = (ArrayList<Person>) data.getSerializableExtra("RecArray");

        TableLayout tbl = new TableLayout(this);
        TextView[] tv = new TextView[RecipientArray.size()];
        ImageButton delete_btns[] = new ImageButton[RecipientArray.size()];
        TableRow tr[] = new TableRow[RecipientArray.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < RecipientArray.size(); i++) {

            tv[i] = new TextView(this);
            tv[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fill_rece);
            Person p = RecipientArray.get(i);
            tv[i].setText(p.getName());
            tv[i].setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            tv[i].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                            delete_btns[i] = new ImageButton(this);
                                   delete_btns[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.ipad_postcare_landscape_from);
                          d.setBounds(0, 0, delete_btns[i].getWidth(), delete_btns[i].getHeight());             
            tr[i] = new TableRow(this);
            tr[i].addView(tv[i]);
            tr[i].addView(delete_btns[i]);
            tbl.addView(tr[i]);

        }
        recs_layout.addView(tbl);//Adding TableLayout to parent RelativeLayout

    }
```

Here is the XML layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@id/top_bar_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/top_bar"
    android:contentDescription="@string/content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_recipients"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:text="@string/text_recipients"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@id/btn_back"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/content"
    android:paddingTop="6dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_back" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/Rlayout_recipients"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/top_bar_view"
    android:background="@drawable/bg" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_rec_add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="96dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_add" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please used custom listview instead of tableview...

Comment: @Harshid ListView is better than using TableLayout?

Comment: @Harshid Can you please help me with an example similar or close to this?

Comment: http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-custom-listview-images-text-example.html see this example

Answer (score 0):

I think your `textview` is taking all the space in the table row try setting layout params for that as well

For ex:

```
tv[i].setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 3f));
```

And similarly for image button

```
delete_btns[i].setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                    0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1f));
```

And to table row

```
tr[i].setWeightSum(4f)
```

Here the third argument of `float` type is weight of the view as it is set to `1f` for both your image view and textview both will occupy equal space you can change it and set it what you need.

While using weight set width to 0dp for both textview and imageview

**EDIT**

```
LayoutParams lp=new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.weight=3f;
tv[i].setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Comment: For some reason TableLayout.LayoutParams makes the TextView and the ImageButton invisible. Also when I put zero as the width..it makes it invisible, I have to make it LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT/WRAP_CONTENT to make it visible

Comment: instead of tablelayout.layoutparams try TableRow.layoutparams. this will work

Comment: If we set width as 0dp I think we must set weight somewhere, because using the above 2 lines for tv[i] and delete_btns[i] makes them invisible. Also there is no method to setWeight for tv[i] and delete_btns[i]. I am not sure whether tr[i].setWeightSum(4f) is used to helping set weight for tv[i] and delete_btns[i], but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: the third argument of the layoutparams constructor is weight. also you can call set weight on params object

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43972/discussion-between-user2688158-and-vipul-mittal)